# Abstract Algebra ( tutoring suggestions )

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, field-theory, group-homomorphism, algebraic-groups

I'm looking for some good Abstract Algebra courses on youtube but i couldn't find any , so if someone has any suggestions please help me ( or a book with some nice problems would be good also ).

Comment: Have you checked out [MIT](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-topic/#cat=mathematics&subcat=algebraandnumbertheory)'s open courses?

Comment: @Arthur  Yeah they don't have any abstract algebra courses unfortunately, linear algebra only.

Comment: Did you see the one called Algebra I?

Comment: @Arthur the youtube channel or the website ?

Comment: The course. In my link above.

Comment: @Arthur I'm checking it now but it doesn't seem to be complete and the problems are without solutions actually.

Comment: Harvard's Open Learning Abstract Algebra course with professor Benedict Gross: https://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra

Comment: @awkward thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This channel " Ben 1994 " is amazing : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCu5cg_Jd9XSJL_CHUskgkGw/playlists

The guy presents abstract algebra in an incredibly visual way.

- Also: MathDoctorBob : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLF379B0552AD17780
- For a much reader friendly book : Burton, An Introduction To Abstract Mathematical Systems.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you this video:

1. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLelIK3uylPMGzHBuR3hLMHrYfMqWWsmx5. It's quite long (about one hour) but it's very complete and exahustive.
2. Also there is a very good series made by Socratica that you can find here:https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLi01XoE8jYoi3SgnnGorR_XOW3IcK-TP6
3. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmU0FIlJY-Mn3Pt-r5zQ_-Ar8mAnBZTf2. It's one of my best. Abstract Algebra Course Lectures given at Bethel University during the Spring of 2018. Content covers the foundational content of group theory, ring theory, and field theory. Galois theory is also covered at the end.
4. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBY4G2o7DhF0JCgapYKrqibGaJuvV4Gkb. It's another serie of lessons with some excercises here: http://www.supermath.info/AbstractAlgebra.html

Comment: Thanks but i've checked socratica playlist and it wasn't that satisfying , it was abstract hh.

Comment: ok where should i click , the correct answer arrow ?

Comment: @Ken Za: are you satisfied now?

Comment: yeah thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest this books
[Samir-siksek and others](https://www.freebookcentre.net/maths-books-download/Introduction-to-Abstract-Algebra-by-Samir-Siksek.html)

[Allan-clark and others](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/~zarkom/Book_Math_Clark_Elements_of_abstract_algebra%25202.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwivu8Tf1-foAhXXRRUIHUA1CTsQFjAMegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw21FQQUcNNTmDY-lhbma0XL)